# Cannot get table using BS4 Python

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm using a method to get a  from a html, sometimes it works and cannot get any data, just retrieve "Page not found" (I'm able to get in on any browser). I don't know if its a security system to avoid multiple request or whatever, the website is: https://www.bcn.cat/estadistica/catala/dades/barris/economia/renda/rdfamiliar/a2017.htm

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Method:

```
response = requests.get(website, headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) \
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
'referer': 'http://habitatge.gencat.cat/'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

print soup

table = soup.find('table')

print table
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I can't replicate this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

At the end the problem was to break into multiple lines the "User-Agent"